# Reset fieldset and legend behaviour after embeding twitter bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a one confusion with twitter bootstrap. I have legend tag inside fieldset. 
This is my code:

```
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Test legend</legend>
        Some text .. 
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

It is very simple code and it result can be viewed here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/zono/ApzWW/

After bootstrap embedding I have very different view of these dom elements. 
The result can be viewed here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/zono/ApzWW/1/

How I can reset fieldset and legend element behaviour?

I would be very grateful to all means ideas and recommendations.

Best regards.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You really just need to overwrite the Bootstrap styling in your own style sheet Something like the below should do the trick...

```
legend {
    display: block;
    width: auto;
    padding: 0 5px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-size: inherit;
    line-height: inherit;
    border: auto;
    border-bottom: none;
}

fieldset {
    border: 2px groove threedface;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Here's a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/ApzWW/2/

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider to use the panel in bootstrap as alternative, since it already have the style embedded. Here is the example

CSS (adopted from @Billy Most answer) with left-aligned:

```
legend 
{
  width: auto;
  padding: 0 5px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: inherit;
  line-height: inherit;
  border-bottom: none;
  text-align: left;
}
```

HTML:

```
<fieldset class="panel panel-default col-md-5">
  <legend>Sort By/Filter</legend>
  Inside the fieldset
</fieldset>
```

Output:

http://cdpn.io/pJuDB

Answer (score 0):

If you still didn't get the original layout on legend after implementing bootstrap,
try to set css

`legend { float: none !important; }`

This is because i can see that bootstrap is setting up legend to be float:left

Answer (score -1):

To restore the default styling associated with the  tag, you can simply add the following two styles to your stylesheet:

```
fieldset {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 10px;
}

legend {
    width: auto;
    padding: 0 5px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-size: inherit;
    line-height: inherit;
    border-bottom: none;
    text-align: left;
    float: none !important;
}
```

These styles will reset the  and  elements to their default appearance.

Comment: Please write your answer in English, as Stack Overflow is an [English-only site](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680).