# Adding icon next to fieldset legend title

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'd like to add an icon to the right of the fieldset title.but i get this:
the borders are not good can u help me it work in normal way but not with boostrap

```css
.legend_icon {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0 30px;
  padding-left: 0.75em;
  padding-right: 0.75em;
  border: 1px groove;
}
```

```html
<fieldset class="legend_icon">
  <legend>
    je suis une legende
  </legend>
  test
</fieldset>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKXEv.png)

Comment: also what version of bootstrap?

Comment: Does [Reset fieldset and legend behaviour after embeding twitter bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22785634/1016716) help? If it does solve the whole of the problem, we can close this one as a duplicate.

Answer (score -1):

Use `legend{width: fit-content!important;}` to override bootstrap declaretion `width:100%`
[image]

```css
.legend_icon {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0 30px;
  padding-left: 0.75em;
  padding-right: 0.75em;
  border: 1px groove;
}
legend{
    width: fit-content!important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<fieldset class="legend_icon">
  <legend>
    je suis une legende
  </legend>
  test
</fieldset>
```